# Value of type ' cannot be converted to array()

Tags: vb.net

What am i making wrong here. 
I converted the .xsd schema to vb.net class and now im getting that type cannot be converted to array.

The point is we can have an x-amount of classes PodaciOPrihodimaTip inside.

What i've tried is.

```
    Dim l_PodaciOPrihodu As New PodaciOPrihodimaTip
    l_PodaciOPrihodu.RedniBroj = 1
    Dim l_DeklarisaniPrihodi As New PodaciPoreskeDeklaracijeTipDeklarisaniPrihodi
    l_DeklarisaniPrihodi.PodaciOPrihodima = l_PodaciOPrihodu
```

Also i tried with

```
    Dim l_PodaciOPrihodu As New PodaciOPrihodimaTip
    l_PodaciOPrihodu.RedniBroj = 1
    Dim l_DeklarisaniPrihodi() As PodaciPoreskeDeklaracijeTipDeklarisaniPrihodi
    l_DeklarisaniPrihodi(0).PodaciOPrihodima = l_PodaciOPrihodu
```

This is the class

```
Partial Public Class PodaciPoreskeDeklaracijeTipDeklarisaniPrihodi

    Private podaciOPrihodimaField() As PodaciOPrihodimaTip

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PodaciOPrihodima")>  _
    Public Property PodaciOPrihodima() As PodaciOPrihodimaTip()
        Get
            Return Me.podaciOPrihodimaField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.podaciOPrihodimaField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Partial Public Class PodaciOPrihodimaTip

    Private redniBrojField As String

    Private vrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaocaField As Integer

...

End class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change this

```
 Dim l_DeklarisaniPrihodi() As PodaciPoreskeDeklaracijeTipDeklarisaniPrihodi
```

To This

```
 Dim l_DeklarisaniPrihodi As New PodaciPoreskeDeklaracijeTipDeklarisaniPrihodi
```

and this

```
l_DeklarisaniPrihodi(0).PodaciOPrihodima = l_PodaciOPrihodu
```

to this

```
l_DeklarisaniPrihodi.PodaciOPrihodima(0)= l_PodaciOPrihodu
```